# Remove padding between wxPython widgets

Tags: python, widget, wxpython

I have created a basic application with wxPython, got a menubar, toolbar, statusbar and a HTML widget. It looks like this: [image]

as you can see, the HTML widget has padding around it, I'm very new to wxPython, love it, but have no Idea how to use it yet, so I need help fixing this issue.

```
panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

htmlwin = html.HtmlWindow(panel, -1, style=wx.NO_BORDER)
htmlwin.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
htmlwin.SetStandardFonts()
htmlwin.SetPage(code)

vbox.Add((-1, 10), 0)
vbox.Add(htmlwin, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 9)

panel.SetSizer(vbox)
```

Thanks

Comment: `wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 9)` should probably be `wx.EXPAND)` because the `wx.ALL, 9` part inserts a padding of 9 in ALL directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
vbox.Add(htmlwin, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 9)
```

to

```
vbox.Add(htmlwin, 1, wx.EXPAND, 9)
```

`wx.ALL` is a flag that tells the sizer to add padding in all directions around the widget. The last value in the `Add` method is the number of pixels to add as a border. So in the first example, you are adding 9 pixels of border on ALL sides of the widget.